# load all data in view did load or not?

Tags: objective-c, loading, viewdidload

In one project i'm using a XML file of 1432 nodes, i've to retrieve 2 blocks of 100 nodes when user request it.

The point is that i don't know very well permormance on iphone, which of following options should i follow:

1. I load all data in viewDidLoad, then
   when user request it, i open a
   tableviewController passing it the
   block of data requested;
2. Each time that user requests it, i
   scan the XML file and store only the
   block that he need.

Thanks for any suggestion. 
Jonathan.

Comment: possible duplicate of [reading xml performance in objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865435/reading-xml-performance-in-objective-c)

Comment: Is there some kind of daily programming contest that makes the same question pop up in dup/triplicate all the time like this?

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be smoother if you load your XML file in a new thread while the application or the view is loading (the sooner the better). You keep it in memory until it is not needed anymore.

File accesses plus memory accesses will be slower than one file access and several memory requests.